# Android app dies on surface change

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am new to android programming. I am trying to write some really simple apps around basic graphics and input. The app I am working with now uses SurfaceView and draws onto that with a Canvas. It just draws a circle in the middle of the screen, and changes its color every second. Here's my SurfaceView:

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public class DrawerThread extends Thread {

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    private long mTimeStep;
    private long mTime;
    private long mPhysicsTime;

    private boolean mRun;

    private int mCanvasWidth;
    private int mCanvasHeight;

    private int colorIter;

    private int colors[][] = {
            {255, 255, 0, 0},
            {255, 0, 255, 0}
    };

    Paint mPaint;

    public DrawerThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        mTimeStep = 1000;
        mRun = false;
        mCanvasWidth = 1;
        mCanvasHeight = 1;
        colorIter = 0;
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean value) {
        if(value == true && mRun != true) {
            mTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mPhysicsTime = 0;
        }
        mRun = value;
    }

    public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
            mCanvasWidth = width;
            mCanvasHeight = height;
        }
    }

    private void doPhysics(long time) {
        long deltaTime = time - mTime;
        mPhysicsTime += deltaTime;
        mTime = time;
        int steps = (int) (mPhysicsTime / mTimeStep);
        mPhysicsTime -= steps * mTimeStep;
        colorIter = (colorIter + steps) % colors.length;
    }

    private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
        mPaint.setARGB(colors[colorIter][0], colors[colorIter][1], colors[colorIter][2], colors[colorIter][3]);
        canvas.drawCircle(mCanvasWidth/2, mCanvasHeight/2, 100, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(mRun) {
            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                    canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    doPhysics(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    doDraw(canvas);
                }
            } finally {
                if(canvas != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private DrawerThread mDrawerThread;

public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mDrawerThread = new DrawerThread(surfaceHolder);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mDrawerThread.setRunning(true);
    mDrawerThread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    mDrawerThread.setSurfaceSize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    mDrawerThread.setRunning(false);
    while(retry) {
        try{
            mDrawerThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
}
```

I wrote this code based on the Lunar Landing example provided here:
https://gitorious.org/replicant/development/source/3eda8fc3859c243df4a1f892a11e2da84b49cb94:samples/LunarLander/src/com/example/android/lunarlander/LunarView.java#L8

I tried to make it simpler than that so I omitted what I could. So the app is working until I change from profile view to landscape OR use the Recents button. Both of these actions crash my app on the  canvas.drawColor(...) line in function doDraw(), nullpointer exception. How can I this problem?

Second question: I tried to limit my drawing thread by putting a Thread.sleep(<>) in my run() in the drawing thread. However, I noticed that while this thread is sleeping, the screen doesn't flip when I turn my phone sideways(go from profile to landscape). Why does the sleeping drawing thread block surface change?

Third question: why do I need the while loop in surfaceDestroyed()? Isn't mDrawerThread.join() a blocking function?

I know basic Java but I have almost 0 knowledge of android programming, so I would appreciate any constructive remarks.
(IDE: Android Studio)

Comment: "why do I need the while loop in surfaceDestroyed()?" - You don't. "Isn't mDrawerThread.join() a blocking function?" - Yes, it is. -- It seems that someone badly wanted to ignore any `InterruptedException` which might occur while blocked in `join()`. Don't do this, remove the `while`!

Comment: Oh, I think I see what is going on with that `while`... However, you may also have a synchronization issue on the `mRun` variable. You should declare it `volatile` to make sure that one thread sees the change the other thread made to it.

Comment: @HannoBinder I set mRun volatile and the while is in the code at the moment, I still get a nullp exception for both the home, recents buttons as well as flipping my phone sideways. Locking the phone, though, doesn't generate the exception and the app continues running when the phone is unlocked.

Comment: Take a look at https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity .  The section above it on game loops may also be useful.